# How do I initialise a List?

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I initialise a list? Of course I'm not talking about:
    List myList = [];
Allow me to show you the issue:

1st I create my List variable (mainList)

```
List mainList;
```

Then I set it to get me the SQLITE output from here:

```
mainList =  await db.query(DBAssist.mainTable, where: "ItemCategory = ?", whereArgs: [categoryItem]);
```

And all is just dandy - except that the await is causing a lot of stress - and I need to initialise the List to something so I don't get the well known NULL error issue.

I'm just curious, but why doesn't

```
List mainList = [];
```

Work?

Comment: do you mean that after the await is done, the `mainList` maybe null?

Comment: @Kiro777 By putting *=* after your variable, you are rewriting its value.

Comment: Hi gents, Yes.. that's right that mainList will be null... - and that causes bad error handling.

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following:

```dart
mainList =  await db.query(DBAssist.mainTable, where: "ItemCategory = ?", whereArgs: [categoryItem]) ?? [];
```

this checks if the return of the the query is **null** and assigns an empty list instead.

Comment: Hi Karim, but that takes us to the 1st issue - setting it to [] does not work.

Comment: what do you mean exactly by it's not working? executing `List mainList = []` initializes  `mainList` as an empty `List`. you can even try it in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/) .


paste this code and run:

```void main() {
  List mainList = [];
  print(mainList);
}
```
it should print an empty `List`